# Kubernetes one image for many cronjobs with kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have git repo with my cronjobs yaml files. I want to use kustomize to set image in one place and apply it to all yaml. How to do this with kustomize?

My files:

```
cronjobs/
├─ cronone/
│  \─ cronone.yaml
├─ crontwo/
│  \─ crontwo.yaml
├─ cronthree/
│  \─ cronthree.yaml
\-kustomize.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [images transformer](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/transformerconfigs/README.md#images-transformer) to *rename* an image across all your resources. That is, if all of your cronjobs have something like:

```
image: fakeimage:latest
```

You can put in your `kustomization.yaml`:

```
images:
  - name: fakeimage
    newName: docker.io/postgres
    newTag: 14
```

And your transformed cronjobs will all end up with:

```
image: docker.io/postgres:14
```

Comment: Thank you! works as it should :)